# How to change the color of placeholder of the Picker in XAMARIN?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

How to change the color of placeholder of the Picker in XAMARIN for ANDROID and iOS both? PlaceholderColor = "white" doesn't work.

```
            <Picker Title="Search items"  TextColor="White"
            PlaceholderColor = "white"
            VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>Item1</x:String>
                <x:String>item2</x:String>
                <x:String>item3</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>
```

Comment: No,  hichame.yessou, Acepted your answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For xamarin 3.6 and above:**

Use the property `TitleColor`.

**For Xamarin 3.6 and below:**

You need a custom renderer for that:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPicker))]
namespace Droid
{
    public class CustomPicker : PickerRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (Control != null) 
                Control.SetHintTextColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(1,2,3));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks hichame.yessou, Does anyone knows the solution of the same probem for iOS also.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS you would do something similar in your custom renderer.

```
Control.AttributedPlaceholder = 
    new NSAttributedString (Control.AttributedPlaceholder.Value, foregroundColor: UIColor.White);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Garett. You folks are doing such a great service by helping people FREELY. stackoverflow.com is surely a superb place to learn.